# Xamarin Forms Frame not rounding corners in iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

Am I missing something here? Is iOS simply not going to round the corners of this frame? It works in Android just fine.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<pages:PopupPage 
        xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
        xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup"
        xmlns:animations="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Animations;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup"
        x:Class="MyProject.MyPopup">
    <pages:PopupPage.Animation>
        <animations:ScaleAnimation 
            PositionIn="Center"
            PositionOut="Center"
            ScaleIn="1.2"
            ScaleOut="0.8"
            DurationIn="400"
            DurationOut="300"
            EasingIn="SinOut"
            EasingOut="SinIn"
            HasBackgroundAnimation="True"/>
    </pages:PopupPage.Animation>
    <Frame x:Name="ButtonMenuWrapper"                         
           HasShadow="False" 
           BackgroundColor="White"
           IsClippedToBounds="True" 
           CornerRadius="20" 
           Padding="0" 
           HorizontalOptions="Center" 
           VerticalOptions="Center">
        <StackLayout x:Name="ButtonMenu" 
                     Orientation="Vertical" 
                     Spacing="30" 
                     HorizontalOptions="Center" 
                     BackgroundColor="White" 
                     VerticalOptions="Center" 
                     Padding="20,20,20,20">
            <Button x:Name="Button1" 
                                WidthRequest="150" 
                                Text="Option 1" 
                                Clicked="Button1_Clicked"/>
            <Button x:Name="Button2" 
                                WidthRequest="150" 
                                Text="Option 2" 
                                Clicked="Button2_Clicked"/>
            <Button x:Name="Button3" 
                                WidthRequest="150" 
                                Text="Option 3" 
                                Clicked="Button3_Clicked"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </Frame>
</pages:PopupPage>
```

For some reason, the question system won't let me submit this without more do-called details. I don't know what else to say. This code works find in Android, but in iOS, the corners of the frame that is named ButtonMenuWrapper which surrounds the StackLayout called ButtonMenu will not round according to its CornerRadius property. If I have inadequately explained the issue, please ask for a specific clarification before penalizing me and disabling the question.

Answer (score 0):

I test with your code , it works fine on iOS .

[image]

---

#### Version information

Visual studio : 16.6.4

Xamairn.Forms : 4.6.0.847

Rg.Plugins.Popup : 2.0.0.3

Comment: I'm on 16.6.1 and 4.6.0.967 which shouldn't make a difference, and dang if mine's not as square as a board.  ???

Comment: If possible could you provide a  basic sample project which could reproduce the issue ? You could upload to github and attach the link here .